# Access Database - Auto INSERT\UPDATE - Qt4

Tags: sql, ms-access, qt4

In a registration software made with Qt4, I open an Access .mdb database,  update it with the user-provided fields.

It has currently a table `clients` with six fields:

```
 CustomerNumber, FullName, CNICNumber, ResidentialAddress, ResidentialPhoneNumber, MobileNumber
```

where `CustomerNumber` is primary key and a number, while all others are text. There are a few records present. But when another record with same `CustomerNumber`is tried to be inserted, there is an error:

> QODBCResult::exec: Unable to execute
>   statement: "[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft
>   Access Driver] The changes you
>   requested to the table were not
>   successful because they would create
>   duplicate values in the index, primary
>   key, or relationship. Change the data
>   in the field or fields that contain
>   duplicate data, remove the index, or
>   redefine the index to permit duplicate
>   entries and try again."
>
> "[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access
>   Driver] The changes you requested to
>   the table were not successful because
>   they would create duplicate values in
>   the index, primary key, or
>   relationship. Change the data in the
>   field or fields that contain duplicate
>   data, remove the index, or redefine
>   the index to permit duplicate entries
>   and try again." "QODBC3: Unable to
>   execute statement"

I then found the `UPDATE` query, but the following code gives another error:

```
query.exec("UPDATE clients"
"SET FullName='"+cname+"', CNICNumber='"+cnic+"', ResidentialAddress='"+caddress+"', ResidentialPhoneNumber='"+cphone+"', MobileNumber='"+cmobile+"'"
"WHERE CustomerNumber="+cnumber+";");
```

The variables `cname, cninc, caddresss, cphone, cmobile, cnumber` are strings with values. But the error with the above code is:

> QODBCResult::exec: Unable to execute
>   statement: "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver
>   Manager] Function sequence error" 
>   "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]
>   Function sequence error" "QODBC3:
>   Unable to execute statement"

What is the solution to this, i.e. how to insert a new record when the primary key is not present but update existing record with same primary key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing spaces.  The actual command you are executing is equivalent to

```
    query.exec("UPDATE clientsSET Fullname...
```

there is no such table as clientsSET.

Here is what you intended

```
    query.exec("UPDATE clients"
    " SET FullName='"+cname+"', CNICNumber='"+cnic+"', ResidentialAddress='"+caddress+"', ResidentialPhoneNumber='"+cphone+"', MobileNumber='"+cmobile+"'"
    " WHERE CustomerNumber="+cnumber+";");
```

If these are user-input values you are vulnerable to SQL injection.  You need to be careful to scrub all the string values (eg. replace all ' with '').

Comment: actually the  user-input values were causing problems. I used `QSqlQuery::bindValue` and it worked

Answer (score 1):

> What is the solution to this, i.e. how
>   to insert a new record when the
>   primary key is not present but update
>   existing record with same primary key?

This is known informally as an [`UPSERT`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsert). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532435/add-record-only-if-doesnt-exist-in-access-2007) that relates to Access.

Answer (score 0):

```
query.exec("UPDATE clients"
...CNICNumber='"+cnic+"', ...
```

My guess would be that CNICNumber shouldn't have single quotes around it.

```
...CNICNumber="+cnic+", ...
```

But it's impossible to tell for sure without knowing your table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with:

```
+ " SET FullName='"+cname+ ...
+ " WHERE CustomerNumber="+cnumber+";");
```

in the second and third row?