# Update or insert data depending on whether row exists in access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to find an efficient way to perform an UPDATE if a row already exists in a table, or an INSERT if the row doesn't exist.I use Microsoft access

this is the method i use .open a transaction, SELECT to find if the row exists, INSERT if it doesn't exist or UPDATE if it exists, commit transaction.is there any easy method to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @HansUp pointed out in his comment, there is a good discussion about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199417/upserting-in-ms-access), but to summarize:

The recommended approach is to do a SELECT (or something similar) first to see if the row exists, and then issue an INSERT or UPDATE as required.