# MS Access UPSERT (Update/Insert) SQL

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I know this question must have been asked a million times but I have yet to find a "NON-VBA" solution to this in MS Access 2007 SQL.

I am using 2 Tables **TBLDestination** and **TBLSource**. I have to update the destination table records from source table records when a matching ID is found. For a non-matching ID (i.e. new ID) I want to insert the new record 
(Please refer the tables below).

```
-----TBLSource-------
ID (match if ID exists in Destination table)
EmpName
EmpAdd

---TBLDestination-----
ID
EmpName (to be updated/inserted)
EmpAdd (to be updated/inserted)
Salary
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS Access doesn't have an equivalent to UPSERT where you can do both in a single query.

However, you can get the same effect by doing an UPDATE query where you join to the table you want to update from. Then you do an INSERT query where you OUTER JOIN to the table and return only those where it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks Rabbit. I wanted to make sure that I am not missing out on anything here. Its unfortunate that this ends up being a 2 step process.

Comment: Yeah, it would be nice if they add that at some point. It's not too difficult, you just want to make sure you get the joins correct so you overwrite the correct rows and insert the correct rows.

Comment: Is it possible for us to write a UDF to perform this action. If so any thoughts?

Comment: You mean in VBA? Your question was specifically to exclude VBA. But sure, you can do this in VBA but it sounds like the solutions you found when researching this were all VBA functions.

Comment: Rabbit that is correct. Though I'd like to create a dynamic Upsert function which would function like SQL server's upsert function. Rather than me running the code from VBA or Macro , I should be able to run this from a SQL statement. Hope it makes sense :/

Comment: You can do a convoluted workaround where you use a SELECT and pass in all the necessary information to a VBA function. But it would be RBAR and frankly not worth the trouble and overhead. Something like `SELECT VBAUpsertFunction('KeyField', 'TableName', 'KeyValue', 'Field1Name', 'Field1Value', 'Field2Name', Field2Value', etc...) FROM TableName`

Comment: Do you have a VBA code that can perform the above?

Comment: No, never had to write something like that. Was always easier to create 2 queries.

Answer (score 3):

Access DOES have the equivalent using an `UPDATE` with a `LEFT JOIN`. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37014004/78522).