# MS Access VBA Upsert/Insert/Update query on button press

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form in **Access** with ONE button. Button **push 1** should insert values `(UserID,Now(),Date())` into **tbl** fields `(UserID,Time_In,WorkDate)`.

Button **push 2** should insert value `(Now())` into **tbl** field `(Time_Out)`.

Best way I can figure to do this is with an insert/update statement; with pseudo syntax:

```
If UserID = UserID and WorkDat e= Date() THEN SET Time_Out = Now()

ELSE

Insert into tbl (UserID,WorkDate,Time_In).
```

As much as I've read **Access** doesn't handle Upserts very well, is there a way I can do this?

I've read this:
 [Upserting in MS-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199417/upserting-in-ms-access)

and I couldn't quite understand the suggested answer here:
[MS Access UPSERT (Update/Insert) SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744954/ms-access-upsert-update-insert-sql)

Thanks in advance,

Jof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open recordset with UserID = UserID and WorkDate= Date() where condition, if Recordcount > 0, use Edit method, else use AddNew method and update recordset. Something like this:

```
Dim rst As Recordset

Set rst = DBEngine(0)(0).OpenRecordset("select * from TimeTable where UserID = " & UserId & " and WorkDate= #" & Format(Date, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "#")

With rst
    If .RecordCount > 0 Then
        .Edit
        !Time_Out = Now()
    Else
        .AddNew
        !UserId = UserId
        !WorkDate = Date
        !Time_In = Now
    End If
    .Update
End With

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
```

Comment: So Currently, i'm trying to run SQL on btn_click:

Dim SQL as String

SQL="etc"

DoCmd.RunSQL SQL

Are you suggesting replacing all that with the above?

Comment: SQL also OK, few SQL solutions proposed in answers you refered, but I prefer this way

Comment: For tasks like this, DAO is faster and smarter then calling SQL.