# MS Access Query to get entry time and exit time for each ID

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need help to with an attendance table in access, in my company we have a single card reader which provides access in/out of the facility.

I was able to extract from the software an excel sheet which I later imported to access, the column headers(fields) are in a temporary table as follows.

The problem is staff go in & out of the facility a lot during the course of the day, I need to get the first and last entry time for each day per CardID to add to another table.

```
*AttendanceDate* - *AttendanceTime* - *CardID*
10/09/2017 - 08:00:00 - 123  
10/09/2017 - 09:20:00 - 123  
10/09/2017 - 10:00:00 - 123  
10/09/2017 - 15:00:00 - 123  
10/09/2017 - 09:00:00 - 675  
10/09/2017 - 12:00:00 - 675  
11/09/2017 - 09:00:00 - 675  
11/09/2017 - 16:00:00 - 675
```

I need to create a query that will get the for every cardID the first and last record of time per day and append it to another sheet to get the results like this.

```
*AttendanceDate* - *EntryTime* - *ExitTime* - *CardID*
10/09/2017 - 08:00:00 - 15:00:00 - 123  
10/09/2017 - 09:00:00 - 12:00:00 - 675  
11/09/2017 - 09:00:00 - 16:00:00 - 675
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an aggregation query:

```
select AttendanceDate, min(AttendanceTime) as entrytime,
       max(AttendanceTime) as exittime, CardId
from t
group by AttendanceDate, CardId;
```

To add this to another table, you would use either `select into` (to create the table) or `insert` (if the table is already created).

The insert would look like this:

```
insert into t2(AttendanceDate, entrytime, exittime, CardId)
    select AttendanceDate, min(AttendanceTime) as entrytime,
           max(AttendanceTime) as exittime, CardId
    from t
    group by AttendanceDate, CardId;
```

I don't believe MS Access supports "upsert", which would be a single operation to do both.  So, create a unique index on the two columns:

```
create unique index unq_t_AttendanceDate_CardId on t(AttendanceDate, CardId);
```

Then attempt to do an insert.  If that fails, then do an update. Here is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199417/upserting-in-ms-access) on that topic.

Comment: Gordon you are a star!! If I need to check another table with the same design as your query's output, if there is a similar date and cardID entry then update if not then insert is it possible?

Comment: I've ready your recent edit and I've read the post, however my skills in access are very limited. How would I create a unique index on my query then check with my other table?

Comment: @HusseinSherif . . . You can execute the statement (replacing the correct table name).  I'm sure there is a way through the GUI, but I don't know hte specific commands.  The answer to the other question shows the specific code to run for checking the insert error and then running the update.

Answer (score 1):

Consider running two action queries back to back:

1. Append query with aggregation and [NOT IN / NOT EXISTS / LEFT JOIN...NULL](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/) clause (still compliant in MS Access though an SQL Server link) where only new *CardIDs* and *AttendanceDate* pairs are appended.
2. Update query using domain aggregates, [DMin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/application-dmin-method-access) and [DMax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/application-dmax-method-access) (as aggregate query joins are not updateable queries) where  existing *CardIDs* and *AttendanceDate* pairs are updated.

**Append Query** *(appends only new CardIDs and AttendanceDate pairings, using `NOT EXISTS`)*

```
INSERT INTO otherTable (CardID, AttendanceDate, EntryTime, ExitTime)
SELECT t.CardId, t.AttendanceDate, MIN(t.AttendanceTime), MAX(t.AttendanceTime)
FROM originTable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT 1 FROM otherTable sub
    WHERE sub.CardID = t.CardID AND sub.AttendanceDate = t.AttendanceDate)
GROUP BY t.CardID, t.AttendanceDate;
```

**Update Query** *(updates only existing CardIDs and AttendanceDate pairings, using domain aggregates)*

```
UPDATE otherTable t1 INNER JOIN originTable t2 
    ON t1.CardID = t2.CardID AND t1.AttendanceDate = t2.AttendanceDate
SET t1.entrytime = DMin("AttendanceTime", "originTable", "CardID=" & t1.CardID & 
                        " AND AttendanceDate=#" & t1.AttendanceDate & "#"),
    t1.exittime = DMax("AttendanceTime", "originTable", "CardID=" & t1.CardID & 
                       " AND AttendanceDate=#" & t1.AttendanceDate & "#")
```

Comment: I've tried your solution Parfait it perfectly works!

Comment: update: The update query is not working properly, it clears out all the other table.

Comment: update: The update query is not working properly, it clears out all the other table. I have 1200 records in the append query out of 3340. The update query attempts to update 3340 in the new "other table"

Comment: Look at the `SELECT` version of update query (fill ... accordingly): `SELECT t1.entrytime, DMin(...), t1.exittime, DMax(...) FROM otherTable t1 INNER JOIN originTable t2 ON ...` Does it render the values needed for update?

Comment: I'm not sure it might be an error from my part, I've decided that only an insert query is sufficient, thank youuuuuuuuuuu!!!

Answer (score 0):

An "upsert" is certainly possible, if the tables have a unique key.

This old tip from *Smart Access* is one of my favourites:

> **Update and Append Records with One Query**
>
> *By Alan Biggs*
>
> Did you know that you can use an update query in Access to both update
>   and add records at the same time? This is useful if you have two
>   versions of a table, tblOld and tblNew, and you want to integrate the
>   changes from tblNew into tblOld.
>
> Follow these steps:
>
> Create an update query and add the two tables. Join the two tables by
>   dragging the key field of tblNew onto the matching field of tblOld.
>
> 1. Double-click on the relationship and choose the join option that includes all records from tblNew and only those that match from
>      tblOld.
> 2. Select all the fields from tblOld and drag them onto the QBE grid.
> 3. For each field, in the Update To cell type in tblNew.FieldName, where FieldName matches the field name of tblOld.
> 4. Select Query Properties from the View menu and change Unique Records to False. (This switches off the DISTINCTROW option in the SQL
>      view. If you leave this on you'll get only one blank record in your
>      results, but you want one blank record for each new record to be added
>      to tblOld.)
> 5. Run the query and you'll see the changes to tblNew are now in tblOld.
>
> This will only add records to tblOld that have been added to tblNew.
>   Records in tblOld that aren't present in tblNew will still remain in
>   tblOld.