# MS Access: Update + Append Simultaneously?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables of interest - one is my "main" data table which needs to be updated periodically (ARIES_AC_PRODUCT) and the other is a side table that I pull in new data from (Update_AC_Product). My goal is for Access to update the records if they already exist in the main table, otherwise just append the new records (all with one query). Currently I have two queries for completing this goal... One is an update query and the other is an append query. Note that both tables have the exact same structure (5 fields which are PROPNUM, P_DATE, OIL, GAS, WATER). Below is the SQL code for each query:

**Append query**:

```
INSERT INTO ARIES_AC_PRODUCT (PROPNUM, P_DATE, OIL, GAS, WATER)
SELECT Update_AC_Product.PROPNUM, Update_AC_Product.P_DATE, Update_AC_Product.OIL, Update_AC_Product.GAS, Update_AC_Product.WATER
FROM Update_AC_Product;
```

**Update query**:

```
UPDATE ARIES_AC_PRODUCT 
INNER JOIN Update_AC_Product ON (ARIES_AC_PRODUCT.PROPNUM = Update_AC_Product.PROPNUM) AND (ARIES_AC_PRODUCT.P_DATE = Update_AC_Product.P_DATE)     
SET ARIES_AC_PRODUCT.PROPNUM = [Update_AC_Product]![PROPNUM], ARIES_AC_PRODUCT.P_DATE = [Update_AC_Product]![P_DATE], ARIES_AC_PRODUCT.OIL = [Update_AC_Product]!OIL, ARIES_AC_PRODUCT.GAS = [Update_AC_Product]!GAS, ARIES_AC_PRODUCT.WATER = [Update_AC_Product]![WATER];
```

---

Note that I have 2 primary keys in each table - PROPNUM and P_DATE. PROPNUM is the item ID and P_DATE is the production date. One PROPNUM can have multiple P_DATE entries (so the combination of PROPNUM & P_DATE makes a unique record in each table).

Is it possible to combine these two queries into one so I don't have to append new records and then update the existing ones separately?

Thank you!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upserting in MS-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199417/upserting-in-ms-access) (especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37014004/7296893) by Patrick Honorez is useful for your situation)

Comment: No, it is not possible. Why is running the two actions an issue? Only have to write code once. Write code that calls the query objects or construct the SQLs in VBA.

Comment: @June7 It is possible. See the dupe link (answer by Patrick Honorez).

Comment: Okay, learned something new. Maybe @Urbycoz has not seen Patrick's answer.

Comment: I tried using Patrick's method but it didn't work.. After about 5 mins of calculating it prompted me with "you are about to update 100,000 records" when my goal was just to update 1 record & append 1 new record. The table to be updated has 100k+ records and the source table has 2 records (one for update and one for append)

Comment: @gmag21 that sounds like your join might be in the wrong direction. Please share the attempt