# check and compare two table and update the table 2 how that be possible in access database

Tags: database, ms-access

I have 2 tables in Access database. Both tables have the same column but data is old. I have to update data. There is no unique id. How do I update my data? But the email is same. I want to check if the email is not there it update and if the email is there check other data from it to update.

```
File1              File2
C1 C2 C3           C1 C2 C3
U1 a  b            U1 a   ?
U2 a  b            U3 a          
U3    b
```

Comment: If there is no key value common to both tables, then cannot link them and cannot update. Edit question to show sample data and desired result.

Comment: enter an image may it will help you to understand

Comment: Image simply duplicated the example tables so I removed it. Field C1 appears to be unique identifier. Build a query that links on the common C1 fields and update File2 C3 with File1 C3. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199417/upserting-in-ms-access