# How to speed up bulk 'upsert' in Microsoft Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, dao

I am performing an 'upsert' in Access using a VBA dictionary. I am looping my dictionary keys, and if the key exists in the Access table then I update it. If not, it inserts it. However my table contains 200k+ rows, and this makes the code perform incredibly slow (e.g., 5 minutes and not even 5% had done) as iteration requires that the whole table be searched for the 'LOC' (my key).

Is there a way for me to speed up this process significantly?
My code is below, any help is appreciated.

```
Sub UpdateDatabase(dict As Object)

Dim db As Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set db = OpenDatabase("C:\XXX\myDB.accdb")
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("MyTable", dbOpenDynaset)


For Each varKey In dict.Keys()

    'Table is searched for key
    rs.FindFirst "[LOCID] = '" & varKey & "'"
    If rs.NoMatch Then
        'If the key was not found, insert it
        rs.AddNew
        rs!LOCID = varKey
        rs![Status] = "To Start"
        rs.Update
    Else
        'If the key was found, update its status
        rs.Edit
        rs![Status] = "Done"
        rs.Update
    End If
Next

rs.Close
db.Close

Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

I have found the bottleneck in the above code. It is the line:

```
rs.FindFirst "[LOCID] = '" & varKey & "'"
```

This is used to find whether the key is in the database or not. Removing this (and simple inserting the new data) speeds up the process and it is done in seconds. Is there a quick way to determine whether a value is already in a table?

Comment: You can call UpdateBatch periodically instead of after every change...  How many entries in your dictionary?

Comment: @TimWilliams I have found that the performance bottleneck isn't actually with adding the data, but in the code that determines whether the value is already in the table. I have edited my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upserting in MS-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199417/upserting-in-ms-access). See the answer that describes a query joining tables.

Comment: @June7 I believe the approach I'm aiming for differs enough to warrant a new question. I'm aiming for a performance increase using DAO.

Comment: DAO loops will work much slower than queries. If you need performance, use queries, otherwise, if it's a tutorial example or a performance experiment, make sure that the key column has an index and use `Seek` method instead of `FindFirst`

Comment: @Sergey  - DAO loops tend to be FAR faster then repated sql statements. If you can use one sql statement vs "many" loops, then you are 100% correct. However, if each loop has to execute a WHOLE sql statement (such as a insert), then that is very slow - about 100x slower then a DAO loop. So one sql vs DAO loop, you are 100% correct. However, if you can replace a loop with repeating sql statements inside of that loop with DAO, you see about 100x improvement in code speed.

Comment: See June7's dupe. You can solve this with a single query, which is way faster than the VBA approach. I assume Sergey refers to that.

Comment: How big is the "list" of keys we going to search for in the passed collection will determine if we can execute a single query with a large number of conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First up:
How large is the dict collection. (5, 10, or 1000???).

Next up, is the LOCID a indexed column in that table “MyTable”.

If LOCID is already aN indexed column, then you can use the following code. It should speed things up by about 100, or more times:

It is assumed that the table is NOT a linked table, but in fact a table in the database.

Note that you must open the table in question as “actable” – that is the default, so I removed the dbOpenDynaset)

This code will do the trick:

```
Dim db        As DAO.Database
Dim rs        As DAO.Recordset


Set db = OpenDatabase("C:\XXX\myDB.accdb")
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("MyTable")     ' <--- note this!!!

rs.Index = "LOCID"

For Each varKey In dict.Keys()

  'Table is searched for key
  rs.Seek "=", varKey
  If rs.NoMatch = True Then
      'If the key was not found, insert it
      rs.AddNew
      rs!LOCID = varKey
      rs![Status] = "To Start"
      rs.Update
  Else
      'If the key was found, update its status
      rs.Edit
      rs![Status] = "Done"
      rs.Update
  End If
Next

rs.Close
db.Close
```

You will also need to determine the name of the actual index on column LOCID. I used LOCID in above, but you best open the database with access, flip the table into design mode, and then hit the ribbon "indexs" button. If LOCID is the primary key, then a good possibility is the index is named PrimaryKey. So you NEED the name of the index.

Answer (score 0):

ditto others' advice;  fundamentally don't do a loop.  do an action query (append or update).

it is the most frequently seen difference between a 'programmer' and a 'database developer'......

Comment: I think we all agree. However a object that contains a list of keys is being passed to the routine. It not clear as to the origin of this list, but as written the supplied data is NOT in a table format, or from a data source we know. No question if that data comes from some table source, then action queries are preferred. The var “dict” is a object, and it not even known if that data comes from a table in the given posted code. If there is a way to take a object collection, and convert that into a query then I am all ears.