# Operations between linked tables and native tables

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access

I have three identical tables, one on MySQL, one linked to this one on Access by ODBC, and a native in the same Access database.

When I update the table on MySQL, the linked table on Access updates, and vice versa. But I would like to know if it is possible that the linked table updates the native table (and vice versa)?

[Access table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnKLO.png) 
[MySQL table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4v70h.png)

Comment: *When I update the table on MySQL, the linked table on Access updates* No until you refresh (maybe by autorefresh setting). MySQL update event do not trigger anything in Access. *the linked table updates the native table* No. From the Access side each refresh gives all records as new ones, even none was changed. So you must compare new state with locally stored previous one for to detect data changes.

Comment: Yes, I need to refresh, but it's auto when Access isn't open. But for the relation between "linked table" and "native table", it's not possible at all? I mean, yes, it can't be auto, so can I create an Access query that, once activated (with a command), takes the data from the "linked" table and puts it in the "native" table. Then I will be able to perform operations on the "native" table with the data from the "linked" table.

Comment: I don't understand your task yet... does your data depends not on a data stored in another table but on an event occured in another table?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not naturally English-speaking, so maybe I didn't make myself clear. So, my "linked" table on Access is connected by ODBC to my MySQL table (so when I update MySQL, I refresh Access, the "linked" table updates, and vice versa). But I would like to know if I can take the data from my "Linked" table and put it in a "native" table.  (when I want, as if I pressed a button that says "Hey linked table, I'm coming to take your data to copy it to another table!").

Comment: *Sorry, I'm not naturally English-speaking* /me too. *I would like to know if I can take the data from my "Linked" table and put it in a "native" table.* No problems. Simple `SELECT * INTO native_table FROM linked_table`. If native table exists it must be deleted before. See built-in help, "SELECT…INTO Statement (Microsoft Access SQL)" article. Or `INSERT INTO native_table SELECT * FROM linked_table` if you do not want to drop existing native table (but you must truncate it before).

Comment: Oh great! I'll try this!

Comment: The linked table is just a pointer to the MySQL table, so you actually have **two** tables, not three.

Comment: Okay, so I try this but syntax error FROM : `DELETE * FROM INSCRITS,
INSERT INTO INSCRITS SELECT * FROM inscrits1;`

Comment: You can't run 2 commands in 1 query.

Comment: Just run the INSERT action. If you have primary key(s) indexing properly set up, duplicate entries will not be allowed. This will allow insert of new records but not deal with edits to existing records.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upserting in MS-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199417/upserting-in-ms-access)

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how the local Access table is being updated. If it is ALWAYS updated say by a few forms, then you could add a after update even to those few forms, and put in code to update the MySQL table.

Another approch (again you only/always update the local tables) is to add a table trigger to the local table. In this table code event, you can actually have it call some VBA code, and that VBA code could then update/insert to the linked MySQL table. Once again, then the two tables will automatic remain in sync.

The other possible would be to add a time + date stamp column to the tables (both on MySQL side, and on the Access side). You could then write some VBA code to sync up the tables. Such code is not too hard, but in a multi-user setting, this can become quite a challenge, since while you are syncing the data, other users might also update the MySQL tables and thus your sync routines might well miss some tables. Database sync software and this subject can fill a few books the size of medical texts, and is a VERY complex subject.

However, why not just always use linked tables to MySQL, and be done with any requirements to sync data? Access makes a great client to SQL server or MySQL. If you eliminate the local tables, then you eliminate the need to sync your data.