# What is the SQL to append distinct rows based on select fields?

Tags: ms-access

I have the following query:

```
INSERT INTO bet_records (batch_ID, ID1_G, ID2_G, ID_T_G, ID_R_G, p1_win)
SELECT DISTINCT (SELECT max(batch_ID) FROM batch_IDs) AS batch_ID, ID1_G, ID2_G, ID_T_G, ID_R_G, p1_win
FROM qry_batch_bets;
```

However, this inserts rows that are determined as distinct based on all fields. I want to only insert rows where they are distinct based on all fields except batch_ID. I've searched for solutions and a few have recommended creating an index. Is there an SQL way of doing what I want?

**Edit:**

Sample data...

bet_records:

```
+----------+-------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
| batch_ID | ID1_G | ID2_G | ID_T_G | ID_R_G | p1_win |
+----------+-------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
|        1 | A     | A     | A      | A      | A      |
+----------+-------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
```

qry_batch_bets:

```
+----------+-------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
| batch_ID | ID1_G | ID2_G | ID_T_G | ID_R_G | p1_win |
+----------+-------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
|        2 | A     | A     | A      | A      | A      |
|        2 | A     | A     | A      | A      | A      |
|        2 | B     | B     | B      | B      | B      |
+----------+-------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
```

NEW bet_records:

```
+----------+-------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
| batch_ID | ID1_G | ID2_G | ID_T_G | ID_R_G | p1_win |
+----------+-------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
|        1 | A     | A     | A      | A      | A      |
|        2 | B     | B     | B      | B      | B      |
+----------+-------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried. What is wrong with the code you provided?

Comment: The above code inserts distinct rows based on ALL fields. I want to exclude batch_ID

Comment: Why isn't 1 row full of As out of the 2 existing in qry_batch_bets also in the expected results?

Comment: Sorry @forpas - was confusing things with incorrect data. Updated so should be clearer now. I only want unique rows based on all fields except batch_ID

Comment: In the table qry_batch_bets there are 2 rows `2 |  A     | A     | A      | A      | A`. Why don't you want 1 of them inserted in  bet_records?

Comment: @forpas - because they are duplicate entries just in a new batch. The background to this is that I'm taking a copy of a csv every hour or so which creates columns 2-5. Every copy is then assigned a batch number in column 1 but I only want unique entries being appended to the table

Comment: Have you tried setting a compound index on those 5 fields? This will prevent duplicate combinations.

Comment: That's what I'd seen in other solutions. The actual table is 20+ columns with numbers and text. That still ok to add an index across all of these?

Comment: Try it and find out. There is probably a limit but since I've never tried, can't say. Google it. You only mentioned 5 columns as needing to be a unique combination.

Comment: Could try concatenating fields and query only enters records where there is not a matching concatenated value. But 20+ fields is a lot. Only alternative I can see involves VBA.

Comment: Did you try a JOIN on 20+ fields? Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199417/upserting-in-ms-access

Comment: JOIN on every field did the trick @June7. Can't believe I didn't think of that!! Thanks a million. Write it up quickly and I'll mark it as the answer?

Comment: If anything, should probably close as a duplicate question. Did you use the UPSERT technique?

Comment: No because I didn't want to update any rows - just append. Agreed that this is basic but there were quite a few questions out there which suggests people aren't sure. I also didn't see anyone suggesting using joins so maybe it just about holds its head above water... maybe... just.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options appear to be:

1. compound index to prevent duplicating combinations, however, you may exceed limit of how many fields can be included
2. Find Unmatched query to pull records in qry_batch_bets that are not in bet_records and use that as source for INSERT - this involves a JOIN on all fields necessary to define unique record - Access has query wizard for Find Unmatched