# Input error when I am using vba to execute SQL

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I seem to running into an issue with my RunSQL statement, I keep getting the following error

> Query input must include at least one table or query

I am sure it is a simple error but I am just not seeing it now.

```
Private Sub Command13_Click()
    Dim SQL_Text As String
    Dim reccount As Long
    Dim dbs As Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    'Assign count of PO's
    Set dbs = OpenDatabase("Y:\Databases\Bulk database\Fabric_Data.mdb")
    Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM PO;")
    rs.MoveLast
    reccount = rs.RecordCount
    rs.Close

    'IF PO count is greater than 0 the table is Drop and PO's are recounted in prep to be inserted
    If recount <> 0 Then
        DoCmd.RunSQL ("DROP [PO_#];")
        DoCmd.RunSQL ("SELECT [P0_#] INTO PO FROM Fabric_Release;")
    Else
        DoCmd.RunSQL ("SELECT [PO_#] INTO PO FROM Fabric_Release;")
    End If

    Set rs = Nothing

    'Insert new PO data
    SQL_Text = "INSERT INTO Fabric_Release ([PO_#], Supplier, [Fabric Name], [Fabric_#], Order_Qty, ETD) VALUES ('" & Me![PO_#] & "', '" & Me.Supplier & "', '" & Me![Fabric Name] & "', '" & Me![Fabric_#] & "', '" & Me.Order_Qty & "', '" & Me.ETD & "')" & " " & _
               "WHERE '" & Me![PO_#] & "' NOT IN (SELECT [PO_#] FROM PO);"
    MsgBox (SQL_Text)
    DoCmd.RunSQL (SQL_Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: Which of the 4 `RunSQL` statements is causing the error?

Comment: the last statement

Comment: If fields are number type, don't use apostrophe delimiters. If fields are date/time, use # delimiters. WHERE clause is not value in this context. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199417/upserting-in-ms-access Advise not to use punctuation/special characters in naming convention. Better would be PO_Num.

Comment: You've got errors in your SQL in the last statement, so it's not parsing correctly. You can avoid this by not concatenating SQL and instead use parameterized queries. Doing so also prevents data loss or corruption by SQL injection.

Comment: Spaces in naming is also not advised. Why save fabric name as well as fabric number?

Comment: I've made the changes but I am still running into the same issue

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @KenWhite, use best practices of SQL parameterization (a concept known beyond MS Access and VBA but for *all* databases and *all* programming languages that connect to them with SQL). Doing so, you avoid the messy even dangerous need to concatenate VBA variables to an SQL string with quote enclosures.

Specifically, MS Access supports parameterization in DAO with `PARAMETERS` clause in SQL that can be binded with application layer values via [QueryDefs.Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/parameters-collection-dao). Therefore, adjust your last `RunSQL` call with the following:

```vb
...
Dim qdef As QueryDef

' DEFINE PREPARED SQL (NO VBA DATA) WITH DEFINED COLUMN TYPES
SQL_Text = "PARAMETERS [prmPO] AS TEXT, [prmSupplier] AS TEXT, [prmFabricName] AS TEXT," _ 
           & "         [prmFabricNum] AS INTEGER, [prmOrderQty] AS LONG, [prmETD] AS DATE; " _
           & "INSERT INTO Fabric_Release ([PO_#], Supplier, [Fabric Name], [Fabric_#], Order_Qty, ETD)" _
           & " VALUES ([prmPO], [prmSupplier], [prmFabricName], [prmFabricNum], [prmOrderQty], [prmETD])"

' INITIALIZE QUERYDEF
Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", SQL_Text)
' Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("mySavedParamQuery")  ' FOR SAVED QUERY WITH ABOVE SQL

' BIND PARAMETERS
qdef![prmPO] =  Me![PO_#]                   ' ASSUMED TO BE A TEXT
qdef![prmSupplier] = Me.Supplier            ' ASSUMED TO BE A TEXT 
qdef![prmFabricName] = Me![Fabric Name]     ' ASSUMED TO BE A TEXT
qdef![prmFabricNum] = Me![Fabric_#]         ' ASSUMED TO BE A NUMBER 
qdef![prmOrderQty] = Me.Order_Qty           ' ASSUMED TO BE A NUMBER
qdef![prmETD] = Me.ETD                      ' ASSUMED TO BE A DATE/TIME VALUE

' EXECUTE ACTION QUERY
qdef.Execute

' UNINTIALIZE QUERYDEF
Set qdef = Nothing
```

---

Even better, you can use a saved SQL query that points to form controls with a `DoCmd.OpenQuery` call that can read directly from open form controls:

**SQL** *(adjust form name and save below as MS Access query)*

```sql
INSERT INTO Fabric_Release ([PO_#], Supplier, [Fabric Name], [Fabric_#], Order_Qty, ETD)
VALUES (Forms!myForm![prmPO], Forms!myForm![prmSupplier], Forms!myForm![prmFabricName], 
        Forms!myForm![prmFabricNum], Forms!myForm![prmOrderQty], Forms!myForm![prmETD])
```

**VBA**

```vb
Private Sub Command13_Click()
   ' AVOID DROP/MAKE TABLE QUERIES FOR DELETE/INSERT
   DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM [PO]"
   DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [PO] ([PO_#]) SELECT [PO_#] FROM Fabric_Release"

   DoCmd.OpenQuery "mySavedQuery"                 ' NO NEED TO CLOSE ACTION QUERIES
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. This should see me through.