# What is the best way to transfer user changes in UI data (insert, update and delete) back to a database table?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

This seems to me to be a very common issue but I've been unable to find any related Q&A.

I am preparing to write a winforms program in vb.net that will create and edit quotes. The quotes will have multiple line items which will be stored in a corresponding database table. When a user is working on a quote they will first query the database for the existing data and from there they will make the necessary changes (add new line items, edit existing line items and delete existing line items).

I know that I can run all 3 statements sequentially (INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE) for the relevant line items but this seems unnecessarily cumbersome. My queries average about 200ms each and to be honest I don't know how that compares, if that's a relatively fast or slow query and if that's super slow, maybe I have a different problem to worry about but as common a problem/use case this seems to be I have to believe some of you folks have a brilliantly efficient way to handle this.

If it matters the data is in an Access database and the queries are very simple (no joins etc).

Your comments are very appreciated!!

Comment: What you are describing is called an Upsert.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199417/upserting-in-ms-access

Comment: *200ms* seems rather slow. With Access as frontend, you would simply use bound forms, no code required for the data editing. You should ask this question in the context (and with the tag) of the actual programming language you want to use.

Comment: Is the program and the database on the same workstation, or is there a network involved?

Comment: Sorry, question updated clarifying that this will be a winforms program written in vb.net.    DB is on a local network on a Synology Disk Station.  I appreciate the feedback so far.