# Transferring data to another table in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I need to transfer some data from one table to another.
The problem is that my current code switches automatically to the first three rows of another table, and not to the necessary rows.
It's about the fact that in one table (Hidd1) I have depths of 0m, 5m, 10m, 20m... and the bottom, and in the other (FdSest1) only 0m, 10m and the bottom.
P.S. the database is huge with a lot of variables

Here is the current code:

```
Private Sub Azuriraj_Fds_Click()
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim sest As DAO.Recordset 
Set sest = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("FdSest1") 

Dim hidd As DAO.Recordset 
Set hidd = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Hidd1") 

sest_stat = sest!Stat
sest_date = sest!Date
sest_time = sest!Time
sest_dep = sest!Dephwl

hidd_stat = hidd!Stat
hidd_date = hidd!Date
hidd_time = hidd!Time
hidd_dep = hidd!Dephwl

sest.MoveFirst 
Do Until sest.EOF And hidd.EOF 
    If sest_stat = hidd_stat And sest_date = hidd_date And sest_time = hidd_time And sest_dep = hidd_dep Then
        hidd.Edit
        hidd!Ismc.Value = sest!Ismc.Value
        hidd!Tsmc.Value = sest!Tsmc.Value
        hidd.Update
    End If
sest.MoveNext
hidd.MoveNext
Loop
MsgBox "gotovo"

Set sest = Nothing 
Set hidd = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: What does this have to do with mysql?

Comment: The database is in MySQL... MS Access serves as a form for entering data into the database. That's why I put #MySQL

Comment: It is most likely irrelevant that backend is MySQL. Should have tags for VBA and MSAccess. Have you step debugged? Doesn't look like "moving" records, looks like updating. Your loop logic doesn't make sense to me - possibly you need two nested loops. Or instead of looping code, SQL might be useful. Might find this of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199417/upserting-in-ms-access. Sample data and desired results as text tables can be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For this to work, the tables must have identical scema and be ordered, for example:

```vb
Set sest = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From FdSest1 Order By sest_stat, sest_dep, sest_date, sest_time") 

Set hidd = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From Hidd1 Order By hidd_stat, hidd_dep, hidd_date, hidd_time")
```