# SQL - Only add data that is not already in table depending on date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables in MS Access and want to insert all data that is not already in the table depending on the latest entry. The tables look like this:

Table MTM_temp as t:

| ID | AP | MTM_group | MTM_time | valid_from | Material |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1123 | 1254 | FPL | 18,4 | 02.04.2023 | 1789 |
| 126 | 1348 | FPL | 19,2 | 02.04.2023 | 1235 |

Table MTM as m

| ID | Material | MTM_group | MTM_time | valid_from |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1789 | FPL | 20,1 | 10.08.2021 |
| 2 | 1789 | FPL | 22,4 | 05.05.2022 |
| 3 | 1789 | FPL | 20,1 | 01.02.2023 |

In the table MTM I later want to lookup one valid MTM_time for one MTM_Group and the current date.

Each week there will be a MTM_temp table from an import. I want to insert each record where the following logic applies:

First, I want to find the latest entry from MTM that matches the conditions: t.Material =m.Material, t.MTM_Group = m.MTM_Group, t.MTM_time = m.MTM_time.
If there is a match, there will be no INSERT. If not there will be a new insert.

In the example Row 1 of MTM_temp would be added to MTM, as well as row 2.

I tried using a WHERE NOT EXSITS but that doesn't work as intended:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO MTM ([Material], [MTM_time] ,[MTM_GROUP],[valid_from]) " _ 
           & "SELECT t.[Material], t.[MTM_time], t.[MTM_GROUP], t.[valid_from] " _
            & "FROM MTM_temp t " _
            & "WHERE NOT EXISTS ( " _
                    & "SELECT 1 " _
                    & "FROM MTM m " _
                    & "WHERE m.[Material] = t.[Material] " _
                    & "AND m.[MTM_time] = t.[MTM_time] " _
                    & "AND m.[MTM_GROUP] = t.[MTM_GROUP]) " _
                    & "AND m.[valid_from] > t.[valid_from]")
```

I would appreciate any help or hint in the right direction.

**EDIT:**

Example where the logic doesnt work yet:

This is the current table of MTM:

[MTM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5M2BX.png)

MTM_temp looks like this:

[MTM_temp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5312k.png)

The entry in Temp should be inserted, since the most recent entry in MTM is different in MTM Zeit (MTM_time). So the comparsion in the WHERE NOT EXSISTS should only be done on the most recent entry.

I Hope this clears up how the logic should work

Comment: "Doesn't work as intended" means what - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Right off, `SELECT 1` syntax is not valid - `SELECT TOP 1 ID`. Expand sample data to include records that would match and cause insert rejection.

Comment: Logic for your criteria is not clear to me. If there is a match for an MTM group/material/time/date, no records for that group should append?

Comment: what you are trying to do is called an upsert.  Access doesn't have that piece of syntactic sugar but an upsert is basically just a select statement followed by either an update or an insert.  see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199417/upserting-in-ms-access  If your query isn't complicated and your sql skills are up to the task then the left join approach is slickest but otherwise start with a select or lookup and if null records are returned then insert otherwise update.  I usually wrap the select, if, update, insert into one public vba function called Upsert.

Comment: @June7, `SELECT 1` is valid in SQL and works for `EXISTS` subqueries (not `IN` subqueries) where `SELECT` clause is not evaluated and so `1`, `*`, even `NULL` works. But I agree with you, OP needs to explain what is not working: error, undesired result, nothing?

Comment: @Parfait, thanks, my first attempt to test `SELECT 1` failed, so tried again and learned something new. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simply fix the SQL syntax error towards the end with last `AND` condition written outside the subquery where `m` is out of scope.

Also, consider using a stored query which can be more efficient (since database caches best execution plan) and you avoid syntax errors with messy VBA concatenation since you cannot save a query through design window that contains syntax errors.

**SQL** *(save as stored query)*

```sql
INSERT INTO MTM ([Material], [MTM_time], [MTM_GROUP], [valid_from]) 
SELECT t.[Material], t.[MTM_time], t.[MTM_GROUP], t.[valid_from] 
FROM MTM_temp t 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
    SELECT 1 
    FROM MTM m 
    WHERE m.[Material] = t.[Material] 
      AND m.[MTM_time] = t.[MTM_time] 
      AND m.[MTM_GROUP] = t.[MTM_GROUP] 
      AND m.[valid_from] > t.[valid_from]
)
```

**VBA** *(no need to close action queries)*

```vb
DoCmd.OpenQuery "mySavedAppendQuery"
```

Comment: This fixes alot of issues. Thanks.
I will defenilty swtich to using stored queries.

One logic mistake is still there. I edited the post with an example

Answer (score 0):

I found a Solution that is working as intended, although it seems to be overly complicated.

Is there a smart way to do this:

```
INSERT INTO MTM ( Material, [MTM Zeit], [MTM Group], Gueltig_ab )
    SELECT t.[Material], t.[MTM Zeit], t.[MTM Group], t.[Gueltig_ab]
    FROM MTM_temp AS t
    WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
        SELECT m.[MTM Zeit],m.[MTM Group], m.[Material], m.[Gueltig_ab]
        FROM MTM m
        INNER JOIN ( 
             SELECT [Material], [MTM Group], MAX([Gueltig_ab]) AS [Gab]
             FROM MTM
             GROUP BY [Material], [MTM Group]
           ) x ON x.[Material] = m.[Material] AND x.[Gab] = m.[Gueltig_ab] AND x.[MTM Group] = m.[MTM Group]
        WHERE m.[Material] = t.[Material] 
          AND m.[MTM Zeit] = t.[MTM Zeit] 
          AND m.[MTM Group] = t.[MTM Group]
    );
```